# Is it possible to have dynamic files with the contents being at some internet resource?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Maybe this is a stupid question, because, if this was trivial, Dropbox and other similar tools would have made use of the functionality. And if it was trivial it would create horrible security holes. So, ok, it is not trivial, but why? What (and where) should one do to enable this kind of functionality?

Comment: Perhaps a FUSE based HTTP file-system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this using WebDAV and davfs2.  See [WebDAV mounting under linux](http://camille.wordpress.com/2006/03/12/webdav-mounting-under-linux/) for details, but I repeat the highlights below:

```
mkdir /mnt/webFolders
mount.davfs2 https://dav.test.com/share/ /mnt/webFolders
umount /mnt/webFolders
```